# GTK+ line numbering for Text View

Tags: c, gtk

I'm designing an editor in GTK+ and wanted to add a feature of the gedit text editor to represent the line number at the left side of the text. I've added an [image of gedit showing the line number at the left of each line](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hhZ6P72REuY/T64Xmfba4SI/AAAAAAAAA-0/MKubycxNXdY/s1600/grub-timeout.png). I require guidance of which widget I should use and how to use it.

Thanks in advance :).. !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get line numbering, use `GtkSourceView` instead of `GtkTextView`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an object called geditview, you can take a look to http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=UbTA_LHqUuoYhNCUyaNFsy91ZqQ&cid=vmd9QnPTRes&s=&browser=Default#L545

geany also implements line-numbers using an object called Scintilla

Answer (score 0):

In textview you can try this. `self.textview.get_iter_at_location(x, y).get_line()`
Documented here http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextIters.html.

x, y position can be get using the following code:

```
 x, y = self.textview.get_pointer()
 x, y = self.textview.window_to_buffer_coords(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET, x, y)
```