# Line numbering from text using gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

I'm working on a program that contains a text editor on it and will be used for programming (which means that the font is monospaced and has the same size in the entire text). As such, it would be useful if it were possible to see the number of each line (paragraph, not display line) at the side of the TextView widget.

In another question ([GTK+ line numbering for Text View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478133/gtk-line-numbering-for-text-view)), it was said that the SourceView widget does the job, but this widget doesn't seem to exist in gtk2hs, so I'm stuck with TextView.

Does the library offer a simple solution to this problem, or do I have to do it the hard way?

Comment: Why not patch gtk2hs to include `SourceView`?

Comment: [gtksourceview2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtksourceview2) and [gtksourceview3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtksourceview3) are available on Hackage.

Comment: @DanielWagner I feel silly for not using Hackage properly and failing to find that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimalist code for using a `SourceView` with numbered lines with Haskell and Gtk2Hs is :

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.SourceView

main :: IO ()
main= do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  set window [  windowTitle := "SourceView"
              , windowDefaultWidth := 100
              , windowDefaultHeight := 100
              , windowResizable :=True ]

  sview <- sourceViewNew
  sourceViewSetShowLineNumbers sview True

  containerAdd window sview
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window 
  mainGUI
```